# Fixing error with array sizes inconsistent

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Okay, I have a problem with my code, but I can't find the problem.  I get this error when I use my code:

> Warning: array_multisort() [function.array-multisort]: Array sizes are inconsistent in /home/sagesca1/public_html/hiscores/functions.ws on line 1506

Here's my code:

```
function findFriends($table){
    include "mysql.ws";
    $user = $_SESSION['username'];
    $xptype = findType($table)."xp";
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT u.* FROM friends uf inner join users u on uf.friend = u.username WHERE uf.user = '$user'") or die(mysql_error());
    $myFriends = array();
    $xpOrder = array();
    WHILE($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $count = count($row);
        $friends = $row['username'];
        $rank = findRank($friends, "$table");
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM skills WHERE playerName LIKE '$friends' ORDER BY '$xptype' DESC") or die(mysql_error());
        while($skillsRow = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++){
                $myFriends[$friends] = array(
                    'xp' => $skillsRow[$xptype],
                    'lvl' => getLevelForXP($skillsRow[$xptype]),
                    'rank' => $rank,
                );
            $xpOrder[] = $skillsRow[$xptype];
            }
            array_multisort($xpOrder, SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC, $myFriends);
            unset($xpOrder);
            foreach ($myFriends as $friend => $data){
                if(dots($data['xp']) !=0){
                echo '
                <a name="'.$data['rank'].'"></a>
                <a href="compare.ws?user1='.$friend.'" target="_self" class="row ">
                <span class="columnRank">
                <span>'.$data['rank'].'</span>
                </span>
                <span class="columnName">
                <span>'.BBCode($friend).'</span>
                </span>
                <span class="columnLevel">
                <span>'.$data['lvl'].'</span>
                </span>
                <span class="columnXp">
                <span>'.dots($data['xp']).'</span>
                </span>
                </a>'; 

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Could anyone help me fix this problem, if you need any other methods regarding my code, I would gladly add it to this question.

Answer (score 0):

For what I can tell the `$xpOrder` array will be `$count` elements long, whereas `$myFriends` will be one element long after going through the first `for`-loop as you just overwrite `$friends` element over and over.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use array_multisort if the arrays you are multi-sorting have the same number of elements. Based on the error it is valid to assume that `$xpOrder` and `$myFriends` have different number of elements which causes this error.

Just do a `print_r` of the two arrays and try to see if you can figure out where the discrepancy occurs.

Check if this code works:

```
    function findFriends($table){
        include "mysql.ws";
        $user = $_SESSION['username'];
        $xptype = findType($table)."xp";
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT u.* FROM friends uf inner join users u on uf.friend = u.username WHERE uf.user = '$user'") or die(mysql_error());
        $myFriends = array();
        $xpOrder = array();
        WHILE($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $count = count($row);
            $friends = $row['username'];
            $rank = findRank($friends, "$table");
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM skills WHERE playerName LIKE '$friends' ORDER BY '$xptype' DESC") or die(mysql_error());unset($myFriends);
            while($skillsRow = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
unset($myFriends); 
                for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++){
                    $myFriends[] = array(
                        'friend' => $friends,
                        'xp' => $skillsRow[$xptype],
                        'lvl' => getLevelForXP($skillsRow[$xptype]),
                        'rank' => $rank,
                    );
                    $xpOrder[] = $skillsRow[$xptype];
                }
                array_multisort($xpOrder, SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC, $myFriends);
                unset($xpOrder); 
                foreach ($myFriends as $data){
                    if(dots($data['xp']) !=0){
                    echo '
                    <a name="'.$data['rank'].'"></a>
                    <a href="compare.ws?user1='.$data['friend'].'" target="_self" class="row ">
                    <span class="columnRank">
                    <span>'.$data['rank'].'</span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="columnName">
                    <span>'.BBCode($data['friend']).'</span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="columnLevel">
                    <span>'.$data['lvl'].'</span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="columnXp">
                    <span>'.dots($data['xp']).'</span>
                    </span>
                    </a>'; 

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think the problem is that some people don't exist on the skills table since they are a part of staff, and I don't allow them on that table, how would I be able to do it since this is like that?

Comment: I have made some changes to the code and updated it in my answer. Of course, it is not tested because I don't know how your database looks.

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/sagesca1/public_html/hiscores/functions.ws on line 1556

Comment: do you know which line it is? is it the one with `BBCode()`?

Comment: It's the foreach ($myFriends as $data){

Comment: I removed the `unset($myFriends);` and updated code, can you check if there is any luck?

Comment: There were no errors, but it echo's out multiple times. You also have unset($myFriends); three times.

Comment: The main reason that this isn't working is because the size of $row is less than the size of $skillsRow.  When I use my username the size for $row would be 14 and $skillsRow would be 102 or something, I don't know how it would go to 102 since I'm trying to only get the players from $friends from the skills table.